# Backbone.js manual clicked checkbox fires, but 'code clicked' one doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a page with two checkboxes. e.g.

```
<label class="checkbox" for="1">
    <input id="1" type="checkbox">
        Option#1
</label>
<label class="checkbox" for="2">
    <input id="2" type="checkbox">
        Option#2
</label>
```

If I manually click checkbox #1 in the browser, the box is checked (obviously) and changes are picked up by Backbone.

If I have a sample piece of jQuery in the page, fired by an anchor for example, that checks/selects the box 'in code', it's not picked up by Backbone. In jQuery I've tried all of the following:

```
$('#2').prop('checked', true, true);
$('#2').attr('checked','checked');
$('#2').trigger( "click" );
$('#2').change();
```

The box appears checked in the browser using one of the snippets above, but Backbone only picks up manually checked box, not the one checked 'in code', even when they're both done together.

I appreciate any answers that deepen my understanding of Backbone events!

Answer (score 1):

Have tried this :

```
$('#2').prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically changing the checked state of a checkbox does not seem to trigger the corresponding change event. This has nothing to do with Backbone and is considered a normal behavior by jQuery.

So, to summarize:

`$('#1').prop('checked', true);` - checks a checkbox

`$('#1').change();` - triggers the `change` event for that checkbox

`$('#1').prop('checked', true).change();` - checks a checkbox and triggers the `change` event explicitly

I've set up a jsFiddle that illustrates your example, check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lucd/2MtEU/).

Comment: Thanks... I tried $('#1').prop('checked', true).change(); Although the box is checked by jQuery, only the checkbox manually clicked is picked up by Backbone.

Comment: How does Backbone listen to the `change` of the checkboxes? You should have something similar to the jsFiddle (e.g. `events:{"change #1": "checkboxChangeHandler"}`)

Answer (score 0):

I've spent way too long on this. The issue I was facing was I was listening to the click event on the checkboxes:

```
events: {
  'click .some-checkbox-class: function() {...}
}
```

I've tried for hours to programmatically check this checkbox in a jasmine test, only to realize that backbone never picked it up. (Everything worked in the browser when I used it as a stakeholder would)

I changed it to this, which had the same same effect and I was able to check it in a jasmine test and backbone picked it up like it should...

```
events: {
  'change .some-checkbox-class: function() {...}
}
```

And in the jasmine unit test, I was able to get this to fire via:

`view.$el.find('.some-checkbox-class').prop('checked', true).change();`